# CCAvenue customization - Help needed

Tags: php, payment-gateway, ccavenue

We were able to integrate, the payment gateway solutions of ccavenue to our Mobile recharge(beta stage)website, although things are working all fine, once the user chooses the recharge amount and goes to the payment page(redirected to ccavenue server - https://www.ccavenue.com/txn/Billing.jsp), there is a form, which asks the user to enter all info like Name, address, country, state, email, ....and much more.

The question here is i donot want the user to enter all this, just need Name and email, rest all i do not want to ask for.

Beta site : Zapcharge.in/beta

Has anyone done this customization. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have experience on integration CCAvenue to shopping cart for online checkout payment.

I dont think these is a way if you want the CCAvenue form dont have the fields like Address, Country etc.

Instead, those fields can be prefill if you submit the request to CCAvenue with those fields' values.

Comment: Thanks Chris, Yes, it can be prefilled, but, this is user specific, i dont want users to get skeptical about the payments they are making..

Comment: Hi Meagar, you may contact the CCAvenue technique team weather is this sitting available, but I dont see much chance on this, rather than you may have an alternative of having a short instruction or privacy claims or help tip for guiding the customers

Answer (score 0):

First of all CCAvenue changed their API code. So now there are two different form submission links, one for sandbox testing and one for real envo. Links are:

Sandbox: https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction

Secure Envo: https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction

check this [Link](https://login.ccavenue.com/resources/integrationKit.do?command=navigateIntegrationKit&rndTkn=98a92e62ad9b8ec0219d542a4012cb0378575db886cd7bc80c22e8c63cff606c#testing_production_environment_doc) for more details.

Secondly, if you have Name and Email information with you, you can just only submit them as all of those fields are not mandatory and also user wont be able to edit these information once they get into CCAvenue payment gateway page. Please download latest PHP Kit code from [Here](https://login.ccavenue.com/resources/integrationKit.do?command=navigateIntegrationKit&rndTkn=98a92e62ad9b8ec0219d542a4012cb0378575db886cd7bc80c22e8c63cff606c#integration_kit_doc) and you will learn more.

Let me know if this works.